# Redirect css (assets) with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

### Problem

I want to redirect my **css files** with htaccess, because the entire path is long.

I try this - `index.php`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
```

And this in my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ /app/view/templates/default/frontend/css/$1 [NC,L]
```

But, the CSS was not loaded.

```
GET http://localhost/css/styles.css 404 (Not Found)
```

---

### Environment: development

- Without a virtualhost
- Direct Access: `http://localhost/test`

### Folder Structure

**Apache Directory (Document Root):**

```
/home/patrick/workspace/ = http://localhost
```

**My "problem" (test) folder**

```
/home/patrick/workspace/test/ = http://localhost/test
```

**Inside /test folder**

[image: test folder]

**CSS path (inside test folder)**

```
/app/view/templates/default/frontend/css/
```

So, I want:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
```

And then, redirect (call) the correct url, like that:

```
/app/themes/default/css/styles.css
```

I try that but doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/css/(.*)$ /app/themes/default/css/$1 [NC,L]
```

---

### Observations

#### 1) I do not want create a `VirtualHost/Alias` for that URL.

My problem is about:

- .htaccess
- Sub-folders
- RewriteRule

#### 2) I can't put a .htaccess in my DocumentRoot directory of apache

Why? Because is my development machine and I have a lot folders inside root. For example:

- blog
- projects
- portfolio
- study
- test
- work

All items above is a folder in my `workspace`, and each folder is about different things, so, I don't want to put `.htaccess` in root, **UNLESS** it really needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want that leading slash in your rule's pattern. `RewriteRule`'s that are in the htaccess file will have the leading slash stripped off before applying the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ /app/themes/default/css/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Works with a `VirtualHost`, but if I try that in a normal url (without a host): `http://localhost/test/index.php` doesn't work.

Comment: How can I configure that for work in a sub-folder without a host/virtualhost? Like `http://localhost/test/index.php`?

Comment: @PatrickMaciel Just put the htaccess file in the folder that your page is in (e.g. `/test/`)

Comment: I do that but doesn't work: `GET http://localhost/css/styles.css 404 (Not Found) `

Comment: @PatrickMaciel if you want to rewrite `http://localhost/css/styles.css`, then it must go in the document root, since `/css/` is off of the root directory.

Comment: No no. The correctly directory for my folders is: `localhost/test`, and inside I have `app/........., index.php, whatever`. I just not tell this in my question in the first time.

Comment: @PatrickMaciel but if you want to rewrite a request for `/css/styles.css` then the rule must be in the directory `/`, otherwise the `^css` will never match. The subdirectory names are *removed* from the URI when rules get applied, that means in order to match against `css`, you must be in the document roo.

Comment: Yes I understand you point, but you not understand. I'm in my computer right? I have a lot folders in my `/home/patrick/workspace` (Directory of apache / htdocs / DocumentRoot), **in other words, my localhost**. So, I have a `wokspace/test` folder (for "tests"). And then, I was testing/studying about `mod_rewrite/htaccess` and I want to do that when I access `http://localhost/test/my_file.php`. Understand? I can't put the .htaccess in my root (workspace) because have a lot others folders, with other rules, etc.

Comment: @PatrickMaciel if you have folders with other htaccess files, *they will have precedence over anything you put in the root*. So if you only have 1 rule in the root, rewriting anything starting with `/css/`, that will be all that it will do, any rules you have in subdirectories won't be affected. There's no other way to match a URI like `/css/` unless the htaccess file is in the document root. Unless you put the rule in server/vhost config.

Comment: So, if I have 3 websites in the root directory: `server/website1, server/website2, server/website3`, I can not have 3 css redirect in 3 .htaccess of each website? Anyway, thanks @jon-lin

Comment: @PatrickMaciel You may be able to handle it using a referer check to see which website1,2,3 is using the css.

Comment: How to replace the `css` of `^css/(.*)$` with regular expression that matches any character?

Instead of doing one for `css` and another for `js` and... I need one to match all requests and redirect to `/app/themes/default/`

Thanks in advanced.